# View the selected option from the dropdown to Chart.js using laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to count the selected disease from the dropdown the the user selected to show in the chart and count that specific disease for each purok.

**controller:**

```
 $groups = DB::table('respondents')
        ->join('diseases', 'respondents.disease_id', '=', 'diseases.id')
        ->select('diseases.disease', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
        ->groupBy('diseases.disease')
        ->pluck('total', 'disease')->all();


        for ($i=0; $i<=count($groups); $i++) {
        $colours[] = '#' . substr(str_shuffle('ABCDEF0123456789'), 0, 6);
        }
        $chart = new Chart;
        $chart->labels = (array_keys($groups));
        $chart->dataset = (array_values($groups));
        $chart->colours = $colours;
```

**result**:

[image]

**chart.js in views:**

```
  <canvas id="userChart" class="rounded shadow"></canvas>

                            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
                            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
                            <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
                            <script>
                                var ctx = document.getElementById('userChart').getContext('2d');
                                var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
                                    type: 'bar',
                                    data: {
                                        labels:  {!!json_encode($chart->labels)!!} ,
                                        datasets: [
                                            {
                                                label: 'Disease 1',
                                                backgroundColor: {!! json_encode($chart->colours)!!} ,
                                                data:  {!! json_encode($chart->dataset)!!} ,
                                            },
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    options: {
                                        scales: {
                                            yAxes: [{
                                                ticks: {
                                                    beginAtZero: true,
                                                    callback: function(value) {if (value % 1 === 0) {return value;}}
                                                },
                                                scaleLabel: {
                                                    display: false
                                                }
                                            }]
                                        },
                                        legend: {
                                            labels: {
                                                fontColor: '#122C4B',
                                                fontFamily: "'Muli', sans-serif",
                                                padding: 25,
                                                boxWidth: 25,
                                                fontSize: 14,
                                            }
                                        },
                                        layout: {
                                            padding: {
                                                left: 10,
                                                right: 10,
                                                top: 0,
                                                bottom: 10
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            </script>
```

**I want to be like this:**

[image]

I want to show in chart the selected disease from the dropdown to count how many that disease in each purok.